# Is $f(x,y)=7x-x^2y+2xy^3-x^3y^4+y^{100}\in F[x,y]$ irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field  with characteristic different from seven. Show that the polynomial $f(x,y)=7x-x^2y+2xy^3-x^3y^4+y^{100}\in F[x,y]$ is irreducible.

Is the polynomial as an element of $Z[x,y]$?

I did something,but I am not sure it is true..

Because $F$ is field $F[x,y]$ is UFD. x is irreducible in $F[x]$ and consider $f\in F[x][y]$ Then by Eisenstein's Criteria (choose p=x) f is irreducible.. Same thing for Z[x,y] 
Am I right?

Comment: $F$ is not the field of rationals, so you cannot apply Eisentstein criterium. And the same holds for $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. In general $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subring of $F$, so your first question is meaningful only if $F$ has characteristic 0.

Comment: What is your suggestion? @Crostul

Comment: Of course you can use Eisenstein's Criterion as it remains true over **any** integral domain ! Of course, prime ideals must be chosen accordingly and etc., but the changes are minor. Read here, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization

Comment: Sorry, generalized Eisenstein criterion can be applied as you say.

Comment: @Timbuc sorry but I was confused...You said, my solution is true for F and Z isnt it?

Comment: @corciacandy Yes, as long as you apply it properly. For example, you must know/prove that $\;\langle x\rangle\;$ is prime in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ and etc. Other than that yes.